# Qt 5.11.2 in Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: qt5, 18.10

Probably nobody can give me a definite answer, but does anybody if we are going to see qt5-default 5.11.2 in the official repositories of Ubuntu 18.10 at some point?

Comment: As far I can understand 5.11.1 is already [packaged in 18.10](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=qt5-default). The 5.11.2 is available in Debian *sid* (see [packages.debian.org](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=qt5-default) and [changelog](https://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/q/qtbase-opensource-src/qtbase-opensource-src_5.11.2+dfsg-3_changelog)). If Vulkan patches are useful for Ubuntu, then it will be included into it. You can try to report bug to bugs.launchpad.net.

Comment: If you really want 5.11.2 in a Ubuntu context, try KDE neon in a live USB, VM or in another partition. It is based on 18.04 and has `KDE Plasma Version: 5.14.1`, `Qt Version: 5.11.2`, `KDE Frameworks Version: 5.51.0`, `Kernel Version: 4.15.0-36-generic`. There's also the [kubuntu backports ppa](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports) for Cosmic which sooner, or later, will provide 5.11.12.

Comment: @DKBose Your answer is wrong :) KDE Neon is based on 18.04 so it won't help anyway if they're asking for 18.10, and Kubuntu likely won't go through the effort of doing it without getting it into the archive. Thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I primarily maintain Qt in Ubuntu.

Yes, I've been talking with other team members, and our goal is to deliver it as an update. You can probably expect this in the next month (as some of us are taking post-release breaks until the codename is announced).

Comment: So, has anything here changed? Is installing `qt5-default` still the way to install Qt as a whole, or only to choose between versions?